# How to get property of treeviewitem

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I need to get a property of a `TreeViewItem`. I am able to get the reference of the `treeViewItem` (named tvi), But in the visual tree which I see it has a property called `DocumentCount`. I need to use the value of this property in the test code. I have no idea how to do that. Any insight would be great. I am attaching a snapshot of the visual tree for a better understanding

[image]

Comment: That's your DocTreeNode instance. Yours. You put it there. Just cast the header: `var dtn = (DocTreeNode)tvi.Header;`

Comment: I am not able to cast the tvi to a DocTreeControl Type. Error says cant change a TreeViewItem to a DocTreeControl.
Just to give a clear idea, DocTreeNode here is a ViewModel and this view model is used for the xaml binding for the elements

Comment: Try doing what I told you to instead. I gave you the code verbatim. Copy it, paste it.

Comment: I did that...says cant change FrameworkElement to DocTreeNode

Comment: OK, cast the data context. Find where it is, and cast it

Comment: DocTreeNode(A ViewModel) is the DataContext

Comment: Is that not what you want? Whatever you want, put it in the data context. If you need something else, make it a property of your viewmodel.